# Changing the MySQL datadir location to a mapped drive under WAMP

Tags: mysql, configuration

I have a WAMP server running on Windows 7 and I want to move the mysql data files to a network share (A NAS device).

I stopped the WAMP server, created a drive letter mapping to a share on the NAS, copied the files from the old location to a folder under the new share

and in my.ini changed
`datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.1.36/data`
to:
`datadir=s:/wamp_files`   (s: is mapped to the \NAS\SHARE   and an wamp_files is a folder)

and restarted the WAMP server.

It now says (in mysql.log):

> wampmysqld: File '.\mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13) 111116
>   12:27:24 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 111116 12:27:24 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

and the mysql service refuses to start.

Any ideas anyone?

(The NAS is a netgear readyNAS device and the share is set for public access)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drive mappings that you create under your login, i.e. through Explorer, aren't available to a service. There's a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/how-to-map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service) that suggests some work arounds and one potential solution (the answer by ForcePush).

The more robust option would be to see if you can change the datadir to point to a network share, rather than a mapped network drive.

Comment: right on the money :) I actually started with it pointing to a network share but probably had some slashes wrong and it did not work. switched now back to network share and its just fine. Thanks.

Comment: @epeleg, glad I could help =)

Comment: amazingly I find myself stuck with exactly the same issue a year an a half later...
what should be the exact syntax for the datadir= to point to a UNC and which user is the service using to authenticate against this share ? (maybe its a permissions issue?)

Comment: the slashes are inverted! correct syntax for my.inf:

datadir=//192.168.0.1/SHARE/data